# Error in importing CSV data in MS SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, iis

As a beginner, I have been learning varied set of concepts by implementing in PHP. I have written a simple PHP Code to import CSV file data into MS SQL Server using PHP but I am getting error!

Note: I am not using MySQL. My PHP code runs on IIS and I have installed all the necessary driver to connect PHP with MS SQL Server. All the other examples run well. This is a importing concept I am trying but eventually could not make it.

The below is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$dbhost="MY-PC";
$dbuser="sa";
$dbpass="12345";
$dbname="SamDB";
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$dbhost;Database=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['empProfile']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $eid = $filesop[0];
        $user_id=$filesop[1];
        $rfid = $filesop[2];
        $dept_id=$filesop[3];
        $assign_to=$filesop[4];
        $first_name=$filesop[5];
        $last_name=$filesop[6];
        $email_id=$filesop[7];
        $password=$filesop[8];
        $gender=$filesop[9];
        $marital_status=$filesop[10];
        $dob=$filesop[11];
        $doj=$filesop[12];
        $designation=$filesop[13];
        $address=$filesop[14];
        $mobile_no=$filesop[15];
        $alternate_no=$filesop[16];
        $project_name=$filesop[17];
        $blood_group=$filesop[18];
        $category=$filesop[19];

        $query1 = "INSERT into emp_details (emp_id,user_id,rfid,dept_id,designation,assign_to,project_name,first_name,last_name,doj,email_id,password,mobile_no,category) VALUES ('$eid',$user_id,'$rfid',$dept_id,'$designation','$assign_to','$project_name','$first_name','$last_name','$doj','$email_id','$password',$mobile_no,'$category')";
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($query1);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $noOfRow = $stmt1->rowCount();
        $c = $c + 1;
    }
        if($noOfRow>0) {
            echo "You database has imported successfully into the database.";
        }
        else {
            echo "File Type Error!!!";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It executes the else part and prints "File Type Error!!!"

Comment: You need to get the *actual* error either from the error logs or by inserting appropriate error checking.

Comment: You should also use prepared statements properly: [Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Since you're concatenating the query with data from the file, you might actually get invalid SQL queries.

Comment: After `$stmt1->execute();` add `$err = $stmt1->errorInfo();
print_r($err);` that will print if error occurred while executing your query.